# Solving inequality-constrained least-norm problem non-iteratively

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, pseudoinverse

I am looking into the following constrained quadratic program in $x \in \mathcal{R}^4$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| x \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & A x = b\\ & x_{\min} \le x_i \le x_{\max}, \quad\forall i \in \{1,2,3,4\} \end{array}$$

where $A \in \mathcal{R}^{3 \times 4}$ and $b \in \mathcal{R}^3$. I would like to solve it without using an iterative quadratic solver.

For now, I am thinking about the following "algorithm":

1. Use the  Moore–Penrose inverse to find optimal $x$.
2. If any of the constraints are violated, fix one $x_i$ at the boundary value at a time, and find the rest of $x$ by the regular inverse. This is repeated for each $x_i$, resulting in 4 different vectors (if only one side of the constraint is violated). I finally choose the one of these with the lowest norm.

Now I wonder if this seems like a sound strategy? If so, does anyone know if the strategy has a name that I can search for?.  If anyone has other suggestions for how to solve the problem without iterative quadratic solvers I appreciate the feedback.

This seems like something that should have been asked before on this site, but I could not find it searching. Sorry if duplicate.

Comment: please specify what you mean by non-iteratively and a motivation why it is a problem for you?

Comment: Your proposed approach is iterative, too. Why the aversion to doing what is already proven correct? And what do you mean by "find the rest of x by the regular inverse"? Do you mean you're actually going to solve a size $n-1$ linear system at each iteration?

Comment: -Rank(A) has full row rank   

-By the iterative method, I meant those methods that start with an initial guess $x_0$ and subsequently iterate using some algorithm until convergence.

-The idea was to check at all relevant boundaries (if the solution is not in the interior).   If one of the values of $x_i$ is fixed at a particular boundary, the rest should be given by inverse. I.e. I need to perform 4 separate inverse operation, (one for each case) then check which gave the lowest square norm.  Since the problem is small, I thought this might be faster than an iterative method.

Comment: My reasoning for preferring pseudoinverse had to do with that I need to solve a lot of similar equations very rapidly, and the pseudoinverse yields a solution in the interior of the boundary in almost all of the cases. I, therefore, thought that I should start with it.

Although this question was about non-iterative methods (as I called it) if I  am to consider using the "iterative" methods, what would you suggest? I was thinking of looking into the "active set method", but I am not sure what is the best in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem has a solution, your strategy is pretty much there, with a couple small tweaks.

- You might have to recursively apply something like step 2 as you have outlined. Imagine that the optimal solution occurs with two or three $x_i$ fixed at a boundary instead of just one. Worst case, this now has **factorial** time complexity in the dimension of $x$ rather than **linear**. That isn't bad in $4$ dimensions like you have.
- Since you have $4$ coordinates and $2$ boundaries each to worry about, you really have $2^4=16$ vectors to consider even in a non-recursive version of step 2 (since you don't know if it's the upper bound or the lower bound that you care about).

The problem you have specified though looks familiar enough that dealing with the combinatorial explosion at the boundary is probably already solved with a simpler algorithm. For example, applying the method of Lagrange Multipliers you can conclude that there is some vector $\lambda$ so that $x=\frac12A^T\lambda$, hence $AA^T\lambda=2b$. That won't really help if the optimal solution is outside your range of interest, but symmetric linear solvers are typically quite a bit faster than more general purpose tools.

Other thoughts that come to mind, if the constraint $Ax=b$ is tight then with probability $1$ (with most common distributions of entries for $A$ and $b$) the system has the maximum possible rank (in your case, a $3\times4$ matrix has maximal rank $3$). If the system were square then by definition, it would minimize $\|x\|_2^2$ (since it's the only solution, so it's the minimum across all solutions), and you would just have to hope that it satisfies the remaining inequalities.

**Update:** Your comment is interesting. In the event that you don't care about the general problem and are definitely working with a $3\times4$ matrix with maximal rank there is quite a bit more we can say about the system.

First, that means the general solution to the system of equations can be represented by $\lambda v_h+v_p$, where $v_h$ is any *nonzero* solution to the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ and $v_p$ is any solution to the particular equation $Ax=b$. Note that $v_h$ is any nonzero right singular vector corresponding to the singular value $0$ and that any major linear algebra libraries can compute those extremely efficiently. Additionally, finding a single solution to $Ax=b$ is also implemented in those libraries and very fast.

All that said, now we have the reduced problem of minimizing $\|\lambda v_h+v_p\|_2^2$ where $v_h$ and $v_p$ are both known and $\lambda$ is just a scalar, still subject to $m\leq\lambda v_h+v_p\leq M$ (coordinate-wise inequality) for some vectors $m$ and $M$. That system of inequalities can quickly be turned into a single lower bound and a single upper bound for $\lambda$. It might be possible that the inequalities can't all be satisfied, and this will be the step where you determine satisfiability of your equations.

Let $v_{hi}$ and $v_{pi}$ denote the $i$-th coordinate of the homogeneous and particular solutions, respectively. Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ and setting equal to $0$ we conclude $$\lambda=-\frac{\sum v_{pi}}{\sum v_{hi}}$$.

From there, just check the upper and lower bounds for $\lambda$ for any smaller values (might not be necessary -- I'm a little tired to think about convexity and whatnot) or if the previously computed value falls outside the interval of interest.

Comment: Do I  still need to do it recursively even if Rank(A) is only one smaller than length of x?. Since each boundary should only have only one solution?

Comment: Also, I am not sure if I understood your last point. How do I apply this?. Could you elaborate, or do you have a link describing this?

Comment: I elaborated a bit. I missed that $A$ wasn't square, but if Rank(A) really is $3$ there's a pretty fast solution to your problem that I wrote up.

Comment: I think you meant to write     
$\lambda* = -\frac{\sum ( V_{hi}  V_{pi}) }{\sum(V_{hi}^2)}$. 

Anyway, this is a really interesting approach. Am I correct to assume that  if $\lambda* $ is not in our interval, then  the solution must be at either $\lambda_{min}$ or $\lambda_{max}$?  

Also, under what condition is this approach possible?. Can it always be done when we have one more column than row in A?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry about the typo. You are also correct to assume that in such a case the solution must be at $\lambda_{min}$ or $\lambda_{max}$ (you're checking everywhere the derivative is $0$ or undefined, where the convenient definition of *undefined* includes endpoints).

Comment: It cannot always be done when we have one more column than row in $A$. It can be done when there is one more column (or one more row...doesn't really matter which) AND the matrix $A$ is as full rank as possible. I.e., it has a rank equal to the minimum of the number of rows and number of columns. This happens with probability 1 for most random matrices and most real-world matrices, but there are counter-examples.

Comment: If $A$ is square, then effectively you don't even have $\lambda$; you just have the particular solution and it either works or it doesn't. If the difference in row and column sizes is $2$ or more, you start getting linear combinations of things with $\lambda_i$ corresponding to the various singular vectors. In more than one rank difference, I'm pretty sure an explicit formula is no longer possible (though not positive).

Comment: You have answered all of my questions which I appreciate.

Finally, if you know of any Theorems/References on the above, I would be really interested in them.

Comment: Everything leading up to the fundamental theorem of linear algebra would be important so that you know the nullspace is a vector space and how its dimension relates to the rank of your matrix. Part of that is that there is a basis theorem where it's proved that all bases have the same dimension. Hence, you can find a basis for the nullspace ($v_h$ as denoted above if the dimension is $1$), and then the whole nullspace is just linear combinations of the basis. It's not a ton of work to show that the difference of any two particular solutions is in the nullspace of a matrix, so...

Comment: any solution to $Ax=b$ must be of the form $v_p+\sum \lambda_iv_{hi}$. There are (tons of results)[https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300306009040] about random matrices being nonsingular, and in literature on singular value decomposition you'll find that the max rank of a particular size of matrix is the minimum of its number of rows and number of columns. Putting that together with Calc I techniques about differentiable functions (of $\lambda$ in this case), you get the desired result.